# How to set style to TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium programmatically?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

**I'm using Xamarin.Android**.

I'm trying to set style on a TextView programmatically.

In the xml file, this is specified as

```
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
```

I can't seem to find the right constant. I have something like the following:

```
cardTitle.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium);
```

Of course it does not work as I expect...

Bu nothing like

> Resource.Style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Medium

What Am I missing ?

Comment: Can you provide some build log about this error?

Comment: This is not a build error, I'm looking for the right Style constant for the XML value TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium